# IOS Custom tabbed application approach

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm newer to IOS and I need to replicate an app that I made for Android.
Basically is a dynamic Tabbed app, at the start only 2 tabs of fixed dimension are shown (the 2 start tabs must not fill the screen widht),
then every time the user push a button on the home tab a new tab with a web view content is added.
The webview tabs can be also closed dynamically and they must disappear from the tab controller.
Also the area after the 2 first fixed tabs must be scrollable horizontally, so the user can see all the webview tabs present.

On Android I did't use the built-in tab navigation but I Did a custom navigation using fragment.

I will really appreciate if you can tell me wich is the best approach to do the same thing on IOS.

Thanks in advance.

P.S I'll attach some pics to be more clear.

application at the start
[image: application at the start]

one tab added
[image: one tab added]

lots of tabs, user can scroll to see them all
[image: lots of tabs, user can scroll to see them all]

Comment: what's the question? You're going to have to implement all of that yourself (i.e. it isn't the built-in UITabController) but if that's what you want to do, go right ahead. Looks cool!

Comment: Well..since I don't know much of ios I just want to know what is the correct approach to do this...any tips that address me in the right way is appreciated. At least now I know that trying with the UITabController is just time lost..thanks

Comment: What you've drawn looks to me like a UIScrollView containing some custom UIButtons.

Comment: Sounds good...thx. Do you have any idea on how to hold all the contents views and load the correct one in the content screen area when a tab is selected?

Comment: There's no problem with just removing a view and replacing it with another view. If you want to get fancy you can use a custom parent UIViewController architecture but you probably don't have to. Here's the discussion of custom parent view controllers from my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch19.html#_container_view_controllers

Comment: Everything start to make sense to me...thanks @matt

Comment: But seriously I don't think you need view controllers in this situation. Read my book chapters on views http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html and animation http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html. It's easy to make views replace one another with animation.

Comment: I got almost all the navigation done!! I have to admit that is really easy playing with views. As you suggested I'm using a scrollView in wich I add custom button programmatically..thx again @matt

Comment: Great to hear this is working out!

Answer (score 1):

[CocoaControls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com) is your friend. Check out [this control](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/altabsview), which seems to do what you want. It's a commercial product, but $19 doesn't seem like a lot of money if it saves you time...

Comment: Thanks for the tips, generally I prefer to not use commercial product, but if can't make it on my own I can consider this solution